# Kia Sedona CRDi cranks but won't start

Tags: engine, kia, sedona

I have KIA Sedona 06 CRDi. It went into the garage for a major service: timing belt; serpentine belt; filters; brakes; etc. I got it back running perfect. 2 days later it won't start.  It cranks over and nearly gets there but doesn't. I have to use easy start to start it from cold. When the engine is warm, it will start first time. The car has no codes stored, so I don't know what to try next. The injectors and fuel pump have been checked and are in full working order. When started and it warms up it runs perfect, but stalls when the engine is not warm enough.

Comment: This is diesel, right? This is probably an issue with the glow plugs or glow plug relay not working correctly.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad without continued support from OP, though I agree with Paulster2